# Accessing Elements created by Javascript- In code behind in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my cshtml i have defined a tag

> I am creating a Image Upload Form, where On File Submit, i am saving the value in a Temp Table(SQL) and returning(GUID) the value thru a Ajax call and Binding the GUID inside Dynamically created DIV Tag(Jquery/Javascript)

```
<div id="dvDisplayImageParent" class="block clear" runat="server">

                </div>
```

Now, using Javascript i am creating DIV Tags (Multiple) (Containing Images and Textbox) and appending it with dvDisplayImageParent.

I want to access the values in Controller

```
public ActionResult NewProject(ProjectEditViewModel model, String btnSave)
    {// Want to values inside my dvDisplayImageParent }
```

How can i do this??

My Javascript is as follows :-
`var img = document.createElement("IMG");
                                        var lbl = document.createElement("label");
                                        var chk = document.createElement('input');
                                        chk.type = 'checkbox';

```
                                    //Assign image path to display the image
                                    img.src = imgPath;
                                    img.id = imageID;
                                    img.style.height = "100px";
                                    img.style.width = "100px";

                                    //Appending it with Dynamic DIV
                                    dynDiv.appendChild(img);

                                    var input = document.createElement("input");
                                    //input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                                    input.setAttribute("type", "text");
                                    input.setAttribute("name", "hdn" + imageID);
                                    input.setAttribute("value", imageID);


                                    //Image Link
                                    var aElemImageLink = document.createElement('a');
                                    //Move Up Link
                                    var aElemUpLink = document.createElement('a');
                                    //Move Down Link
                                    var aElemDownLink = document.createElement('a');

                                    var callOnImageclick = "DeleteImage('" + imageID + "','" + divDynamicID + "'); return false; ";
                                    aElemImageLink.setAttribute("onclick", callOnImageclick);
                                    aElemImageLink.childNodes = imageID;
                                    var callOnMoveUpclick = "MoveImageUP('" + imageID + "','" + divDynamicID + "'); return false; ";
                                    aElemUpLink.setAttribute("onclick", callOnMoveUpclick);
                                    var callOnMoveDownclick = "MoveImageDOWN('" + imageID + "','" + divDynamicID + "'); return false; ";
                                    aElemDownLink.setAttribute("onclick", callOnMoveDownclick);

                                    //Create a text node to hold the text of the <a>
                                    var aElemTN = document.createTextNode('     Delete Image           ');
                                    //Create a text node to hold the text of the <a>
                                    var aElemTNUp = document.createTextNode('     Move UP               ');
                                    //Create a text node to hold the text of the <a>
                                    var aElemTNDown = document.createTextNode('     Move DOWN           ');

                                    //Append the <a> text node to the <a> element
                                    aElemImageLink.appendChild(aElemTN);
                                    aElemUpLink.appendChild(aElemTNUp);
                                    aElemDownLink.appendChild(aElemTNDown);

                                    //Append the new link to the existing <div>
                                    dynDiv.appendChild(aElemImageLink);
                                    dynDiv.appendChild(aElemUpLink);
                                    dynDiv.appendChild(aElemDownLink);


                                    lbl.id = "lbl" + imageID;
                                    var aElemTNTag = document.createTextNode('    Taggar          ');
                                    var aElemTNWantsToshare = document.createTextNode('    Dela?         ');

                                    var txtTag = document.createElement("input");
                                    txtTag.id = "txt" + imageID;
                                    txtTag.setAttribute('name', 'Tag');
                                    dynDiv.appendChild(lbl);
                                    dynDiv.appendChild(aElemTNTag);
                                    dynDiv.appendChild(txtTag);
                                    dynDiv.appendChild(chk);
                                    dynDiv.appendChild(aElemTNWantsToshare);
                                    dynDiv.appendChild(input);

                                    //Appending Dynamic DIV with Parent DIV
                                    var parentDiv = document.getElementById("dvDisplayImageParent");
                                    parentDiv.appendChild(dynDiv);`
```

Comment: Can you show an example of elements inside `dvDisplayImageParent`? And maybe your model code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Got one **alternative** :-

```
string NoOfImages = Convert.ToString(Request.Form["Your Control Name Which You Want To Access"]);
```

Now, using `Request.Form[]` use can get the value's present inside the CONTROL Created using JAVASCRIPT.

But still waiting for a better solution.

***> Help Continues...***

Answer (score 0):

There is no *runat* or *code behind* in mvc. You can't access any elements from controller. I'd suggest watching some of [these](http://www.asp.net/mvc/fundamentals) videos.